# HTML\ CSS Image Alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with getting my images to align correctly using the below code in HTML:

```
<a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a><br /><a href="Source URL"><img border="0"    src="Image URL" style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 1%;" title="Photo Name" alt="Photo Name"></a>

<a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a><br /><a href="Source URL"><img border="0" src="Image URL" style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;" title="Photo Name" alt="Photo Name"></a>

<a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a><br /><a href="Source URL"><img border="0" src="Image URL" style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;" title="Photo Name" alt="Photo Name"></a>

<p style="clear: both;">
```

Using the above I noticed that the images and text appear to "diagonally aligned" and I can't figure out how to get them to align correctly. Ultimately I'm trying to create a grid view of 9 links with pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Exmaple:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img">
    // here comes image1 and details
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    // here comes image2 and details
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    // here comes image3 and details
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img{
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.wrapper{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## How about this? [See it live here](http://jsfiddle.net/xz7jovh0/1/)

```
<div>
    <div class="img">
        <a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="Source URL">
            <img src="sourceImg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="img">
        <a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="Source URL">
            <img src="sourceImg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
        <a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="Source URL">
            <img src="sourceImg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<p style="clear: both;" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.img {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just basically need to get more familiar with HTML parent-child concept. Here is another example

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEVNbq)

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a>
    <a href="Source URL"><img border="0" src="http://placehold.it/300" title="Photo Name" alt="Photo Name">
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a>
     <a href="Source URL"><img border="0" src="http://placehold.it/300" title="Photo Name" alt="Photo Name">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
      <a href="Source URL">Photo Name</a>
      <a href="Source URL"><img border="0" src="http://placehold.it/300" title="Photo Name" alt="Photo Name">
     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  width:1170px;
  margin:20px auto;
}
.parent{
   width:100%;
}

.child{
   float: left; 
   width: 30%; 
   margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have to need valid HTML5 markup and then CSS styling. Modern flex and upcoming grid system can help you a lot for image alignment...

Here is the little approach ...

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background: #eee;
}

a {
  color: #ab308a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.mainContainer {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
}

.video:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5rem;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f144";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.imageWrapper:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.columncontrol2>div {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.columncontrol2>div>div {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.columncontrol2>div>div .imageSection {
  width: 30%;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.columncontrol2>div>div .imageSection .imageWrapper {
  display: block;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.columncontrol2>div>div .imageSection img {
  display: none;
}

.columncontrol2>div>div .textSection {
  width: 70%;
}

.columncontrol2>div>div .textSection h3 {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .columncontrol2 .row3column_33_33_33,
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25,
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20 {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row3column_33_33_33>div,
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div,
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row3column_33_33_33>div .imageSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row3column_33_33_33>div .textSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div .imageSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div .textSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div .imageSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div .textSection {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row3column_33_33_33>div {
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row3column_33_33_33>div:nth-of-type(3n + 2) {
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row3column_33_33_33>div:nth-of-type(3n + 3) {
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div {
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div:nth-of-type(4n + 2) .imageSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div:nth-of-type(4n + 2) .textSection {
    margin-left: -7%;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div:nth-of-type(4n + 3) .imageSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div:nth-of-type(4n + 3) .textSection {
    margin-right: -7%;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div:nth-of-type(4n + 2),
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div:nth-of-type(4n + 3) {
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row4column_25_25_25_25>div:nth-of-type(4n + 4) {
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div {
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 20%;
    flex: 0 0 20%;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div:nth-of-type(5n + 2) .imageSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div:nth-of-type(5n + 2) .textSection {
    margin-left: -6%;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div:nth-of-type(5n + 4) .imageSection,
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div:nth-of-type(5n + 4) .textSection {
    margin-right: -6%;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div:nth-of-type(5n + 2),
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div:nth-of-type(5n + 3),
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div:nth-of-type(5n + 4) {
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .columncontrol2 .row5column_20_20_20_20_20>div:nth-of-type(5n + 5) {
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="mainContainer">
  <h1>Resize the viewport to see the effect</h1>

  <div class="columncontrol2">
    <h3>Three columns</h3>
    <div class="row3column_33_33_33">
      <div class="col1">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipecq/2013/05/RU171465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipecq/2013/05/RU171465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Oven-to-Grill Baby Back Ribs">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col2">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2010/11/101410925.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2010/11/101410925.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Broccolini and Sweet Pepper Pasta Salad">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col3">
        <div class="imageSection video">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Honey-Rose Plum Cobbler">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columncontrol2">
    <h3>Four columns</h3>
    <div class="row4column_25_25_25_25">
      <div class="col1">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipecq/2013/05/RU171465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipecq/2013/05/RU171465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Oven-to-Grill Baby Back Ribs">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col2">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2010/11/101410925.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2010/11/101410925.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Broccolini and Sweet Pepper Pasta Salad">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col3">
        <div class="imageSection video">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Honey-Rose Plum Cobbler">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col4">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101500009.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101500009.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Sweet-Hot Coriander Chicken">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columncontrol2">
    <h3>Five columns</h3>
    <div class="row5column_20_20_20_20_20">
      <div class="col1">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipecq/2013/05/RU171465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipecq/2013/05/RU171465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Oven-to-Grill Baby Back Ribs">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col2">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2010/11/101410925.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2010/11/101410925.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Broccolini and Sweet Pepper Pasta Salad">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col3">
        <div class="imageSection video">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Honey-Rose Plum Cobbler">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col4">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101500009.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101500009.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Sweet-Hot Coriander Chicken">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col5">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Firecracker Chocolate-Cherry Cobbler">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col6">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Firecracker Chocolate-Cherry Cobbler">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col7">
        <div class="imageSection other">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101500009.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101500009.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Sweet-Hot Coriander Chicken">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col8">
        <div class="imageSection video">
          <a href="#" class="imageWrapper" style="background-image: url(http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg)">
            <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2012/08/13/101742076.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" title="Honey-Rose Plum Cobbler">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="textSection">
          <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```